# Export xls file not readable for import time in php

Tags: php, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

I am using below code for export xls file abd it is working file but my issue is when i try to read file using require "XLS/Excel/reader.php" library it return error "file is not redable."
When i save as export xls file and try to import it working.

> ```
> function xlsBOF() {
>   echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
> }
> function xlsEOF() {
>   echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00);
> }
> function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) {
>   echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0);
>   echo pack("d", $Value);
> }
> function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value) {
>   $L = strlen($Value);
>   echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L);
>   echo $Value;
> } 
> // prepare headers information
> header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
> header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
> header("Content-Type: application/xls");
> header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
> header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
> header("Pragma: no-cache");
> header("Expires: 0");
> // start exporting
> xlsBOF();
> xlsWriteLabel(0, 0, "id");
> xlsWriteLabel(0, 1, "name");
> xlsWriteLabel(0, 2, "email");
> xlsWriteNumber(1, 0, 230);
> xlsWriteLabel(1, 1, "John");
> xlsWriteLabel(1, 2, "john@yahoo.com");
> xlsWriteNumber(2, 0, 350);
> xlsWriteLabel(2, 1, "Mark");
> xlsWriteLabel(2, 2, "mark@yahoo.com");
> xlsEOF();
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ library for export it will working fine.

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello'); 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B2', 'world!'); 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello'); 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');
```